# Gson array parser

Tags: android, arrays, json, gson

I have json response in this form:

```
String json = "{\"0\":{    \"title\" :\"title 1\" ,   \"time\" : \"15:00\"    } ,\"1\":{    \"title\" : \"title 2\"  ,  \"time\" :\"16:00\"   }}";
```

And here is my class, I am trying to map it to:

```
    public class News implements Seriaizable{
        @SerializedName("title")
        private String title;

        @SerializedName("time")
        private String time;
}
```

I am struggling because i have an array without a name which contains loads of other arrays.

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
                    News obj = gson.fromJson(reader, News.class);
```

Would anyone be able to guide me into right direction?

Comment: The Json response does not looks good, where are the values of title and time? Secondly What is in News Class?

Comment: Yea my bad, didnt fill response properly and corrected class name.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is incorrect in format. I have added some commas to correct it.

You can solve this problem by using maps :

```
String json = "{\"0\":{    \"title\" :\"title 1\" ,   \"time\" : \"15:00\"    } ,\"1\":{    \"title\" : \"title 2\"  ,  \"time\" :\"16:00\"   }}";

Gson gson = new Gson();

Type type = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, News>>() {}.getType();

Map<Integer, News> map = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Ref : https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples